# When I run this, it functions as usual but it seems to repeat once. Why does this happen?

Tags: python

Whenever I run this I get a "**pycache**" file placed in the same folder as this project - and its only with this project.

```py
def list_name():
    from project_name import name_sorter as a
    list1 = []
    name = a()
    if name is False:
        return False
    else:
        list1.append(name)
        return list1[list1.index(name)]
def name_sorter():
    from project_name import name_digit as def1
    a = input("Full Name: ")
    bool1 = def1(a)
    if bool1 is False:
        return False
    else:
        if a.count(" ") == 1:
            name_first = a.upper()[0] + a.lower()[1:a.find(" ")]
            name_last = a.upper()[a.find(" ")+1] + a.lower()[a.find(" ")+2:]
            return name_first + " " + name_last
        else:
            return False
def name_digit(a, x = 0):
    if len(a) < 3 or len(a) > 60 or " " not in a:
        return False
    else:
        for b in a:
            x += 1
            if b.isdigit():
                return False
            elif x == len(a):
                return True
from project_name import list_name as list1
a = list1()
while a is False:
    print("Invalid")
    a = list1()
print(a)
```

Also, is it better to have everything in one file or in separate files but in the same folder?

Comment: In your own words, what exactly are you expecting `from project_name import list_name as list1` to do?

Answer (score 1):

> it functions as usual but it seems to repeat once. Why does this happen?

Yes, it runs twice - once as a script, and once as an imported module (imported from itself). Each time an `import` statement is encountered, Python looks for the desired module, and if it doesn't already have one cached, it loads that source file in a special way that creates a `module` object that can be cached. However, *everything at top level still executes* when that module creation occurs - that's how the module's contents are determined.

> I get a "pycache" file placed in the same folder as this project - and its only with this project.

It's only with this project because this is the one where you're doing the weird thing with `import` that you shouldn't do. The `__pycache__` is used internally to improve module loading time on subsequent runs of the program - it's a separate sort of caching, that works even if you restart Python (because it's on disk instead of in memory).

This is honestly the first time I've ever seen someone attempt something like that:

```
from project_name import list_name as list1
```

for the simple purpose of giving something *within the same file* a new name. You normally shouldn't try that anyway - if something was wrong with the original name, then just fix that - but the correct way to do it is as simple as can be:

```
list1 = list_name
```

If this surprises you, you need to [fix your understanding of how Python deals with the names of things](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html).